# How can I generate runtime code(C#) using bot framework v2.1.2?

Tags: botframework

How can I generate runtime code(C#) using bot framework v2.1.2?

"Exported as zip" option has only file with extension as .lg & .lu, however i am expecting as .cs file so that i can use bot framework sdk to modify the existing dialog created from compopser.

Answer (score 0):

The BotFramework Composer application utilizes adaptive dialogs which are not compatible with SDK bots. However, you could build a [custom action](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/composer/how-to-create-custom-actions) that would then make use of SDK-styled code within the Composer bot.

Another option would be to build a separate bot using the BotFramework SDK and then access that bot as a [skill](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/composer/concept-skills) from within Composer. Conversation flow would then pass between the Composer bot and the SDK bot, when needed.